# Align violin plots with dodged box plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, boxplot, violin-plot

I have this data frame

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(80, 5, 1)
df <- data.frame(groups = c(rep("group1",20),
                           rep("group2",20),
                           rep("group3",20),
                           rep("group4",20)),
                    value = x,
                    type = c(rep("A", 10),
                           rep("B", 10),
                           rep("A", 10),
                           rep("B", 10),
                           rep("A", 10),
                           rep("B", 10),
                           rep("A", 10),
                           rep("B", 10)))
```

And I would like to plot it as violin plot, aligned with a narrow box plot and grouped by 'type':

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = groups, y = value, fill = type)) +
  geom_violin()+
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.1, outlier.colour = NA)
```

However, the box plots does not align to the violin plots. What is the missing argument to tell ggplot to do such overlying?

Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to set the `width` of the dodging explicitly for both `geom`s:

```
dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.4)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = groups, y = value, fill = type)) +
  geom_violin(position = dodge)+
  geom_boxplot(width=.1, outlier.colour=NA, position = dodge)
```

[image]

---

For a more thorough explanation, see [What is the width argument in position_dodge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889766/what-is-the-width-argument-in-position-dodge/35102486#35102486)

Comment: I'm looking for a way to make boxplots filled with white, while simultaneously retaining positions of both boxplots and violins, and keeping violins colored. Do you know a way to reach this?

Comment: @svavil Yes, in `geom_boxplot`, use the `group` argument instead of `fill`. `ggplot(data = df, aes(x = groups, y = value)) + geom_violin(aes(fill = type), position = dodge) + geom_boxplot(aes(group = interaction(type, groups)), width=.1, outlier.colour=NA, position = dodge)`. See `?aes_group_order`.