# Combined box-violin plot not aligned

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, violin-plot

I want to graph a distribution along two dimensions using a violinplot with a boxplot in it. The result can be really fascinating, but only when done right.

```
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
head(ToothGrowth)
plot <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
  geom_violin() + geom_boxplot(width=0.1)  + theme(legend.position="none")
ggsave(filename="Violinboxplot.png", plot, height=6, width=4)
```

This is however what I get:

[image]

The boxplots are aligned along the axis belonging to the factor. How can I shift them to be in the center of the violinplots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an answer to this question here:
[how to align violin plots with boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012500/how-to-align-violin-plots-with-boxplots)

You can use the position argument to shift the graph elements as needed:

```
dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.5)

ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
  geom_violin(position = dodge) +
  geom_boxplot(width=.1, position = dodge) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```